# ignore в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ли в unity3d что то типа:

```
ignore. touch Screen?
```

Где почитать, если есть, и как обойтись, если нет?

Comment: Речь о том,чтобы в игре для андроида нельзя было управлять игрой. Скажем, пока объект движется.

Comment: Если обходиться самому - нужно юзать CrossPlatformInput, либо свой класс-хандлер - это самый простой способ (там можно спокойно дефать любые условия под любые платформы без вреда для игры), и в самой игре обращаться только к ним (ни в коем случае не юзать Input, Events, джойстики и прочие классы *напрямую*). Либо, дедовский метод из структурного программирования - флаги, но тут объём дублированного кода (под каждую платформу) будет большим... Лично я использую первый вариант, никаких исправлений в коде при смене платформы не приходилось делать)

Comment: alexander barakin, спасибо. Я обошелся включением/выключением скрипта, в котором прописано управление.(т.е. флаги)